# Nestjs stream file dest.on is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, fs, nestjs

I try to stream a file onto api response using nestjs and fs. This thing is simple and supposedly would work out of the box, but I'm getting error:

> _stream_readable.js:638
>     dest.on('unpipe', onunpipe);
>   TypeError: dest.on is not a function

```
import { Controller, HttpCode, HttpStatus, Post, Res } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ApiBearerAuth, ApiInternalServerErrorResponse, ApiOkResponse, ApiTags, 
ApiUnauthorizedResponse } from '@nestjs/swagger';
import { Response } from 'express';
import * as http from 'http';
import { SitemapExportRepository } from './sitemap-export.repository';

const fs = require('fs');

@Controller('api/v1/site-map')
@ApiTags('❤ API > Contents site-map')
export class SitemapExportController {
constructor(private readonly repo: SitemapExportRepository) {}

@Post()
@ApiBearerAuth()
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
@ApiOkResponse({description: http.STATUS_CODES[200]})
@ApiUnauthorizedResponse({description: http.STATUS_CODES[401]})
@ApiInternalServerErrorResponse({description: http.STATUS_CODES[500]})
async loadContentSupportPublications(@Res() response: Response): Promise<void> {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream('./dist/test');
    readStream.on('open', () => {
     readStream.pipe(response);
    });

    readStream.on('error', (err: Error) => {
     console.log(err);
    });
 }
}
```

the complete stacktrace

```
_stream_readable.js:638
  dest.on('unpipe', onunpipe);
       ^

TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at ReadStream.Readable.pipe (_stream_readable.js:638:8)
    at ReadStream.readStream.on (/Users/medi/Documents/wkdir/mygit/site-map-api/dist/server.js:9017:32)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at lazyFs.open (internal/fs/streams.js:120:10)
    at FSReqWrap.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:140:20)

/Users/medi/Documents/wkdir/mygit/site-map-api/node_modules/webpack-shell-plugin/lib/index.js:168
        throw error;
        ^
```

Comment: did you manage to solve this?

Comment: I changed the logic, writing into a memory buffer and streaming result on http response. This way >     const buffer = readable({objectMode: true});
    buffer._read = () => {};
    response.type('application/json').send(buffer);

Comment: mind blown, although i dont quite understand why you would need to do that.. and i guess i need to learn more about readable({obectMode})   any idea why this works?

 if the stream is readable, it should be able to write to res which is writable.  Instead of waiting for the open event, why not just pipe it.. pipe will handle the back pressure and all the chunks for you. no?

Comment: I guess it was the readable pipe stream that could not handle pushing into the http response. A limitation of the framework or mixture of webpack and nestjs frapmework I'm using. Most important is that response works better streaming result over send method than piping the result with a stream over response

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution by using a service to write into a memory buffer and streaming result over http response.

```
enter code here
@Post()
@ApiBearerAuth()
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
@ApiOkResponse({description: http.STATUS_CODES[200]})
@ApiUnauthorizedResponse({description: http.STATUS_CODES[401]})
@ApiInternalServerErrorResponse({description: http.STATUS_CODES[500]})
async loadContentSupportPublications(@Res() response: Response): Promise<void> 
{

 const buffer = readable({objectMode: true});
 buffer._read = () => {};
 response.type('application/json').send(buffer);
 await this.sitemapExportRepository.streamTreeSiteMap(buffer);
}
```

Comment: Can the memory buffer be exhausted in this case? i.e run out of memory?

by 'readable' does it mean somewhere above in your code you defined const { Readable } = require("stream");

interesting, this could work in aws lambda functions as well, as aws functions dont like piping as well. The problem i see with this is the back pressure management for responses that cant handle the data as fast as its being served.

Comment: indeed I'm doing a const readable = require('readable-stream').Readable; and I'm running it on GAE service, same I believe as AWS lambda functions. The buffer is memory therefore could run out. You should size function memories to handle load. I don't think there will be back pressure as todays technos handle quite well streamed data